# How to go back from People.CONTENT_URI without getting an error?

Tags: android, back-button, android-contacts

I want to get the names and numbers of my android original contacts. However, when I reach android contacts list and decide not to get any into my application then click **back button**, I get an error. Here's the portion of my code:

```
public void addContact(){
    Intent addContact = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(addContact, ADD_EXIST);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int ResultCode, Intent data){
    String wl_name, wl_num;
    switch(reqCode){
    case (ADD_EXIST):
        Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                   wl_name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));
                   wl_num = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NUMBER));
               createListItem(wl_name, wl_num);
                }
                break;
    default:
        (Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                         "No Contacts Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)).show();
      }
}
```

**How can I press back button without getting the error. Is there any better way to get the contacts?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the resultcode or, at the very least, whether data is null before you use it.

Comment: How can I check the type of data returned from Android contacts? Can the resultCode be null (even if it's an int)?

Comment: Check `if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)` for good response, RESULT_CANCELED for back/cancel response.  Check `contactData != null` before using it.

Comment: It worked fine with if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) else !! Thank you!